# Add methods to an object with object notation

Tags: javascript, prototype, meteor, javascript-objects

I have the following code:

```
Template.leaderboard.players = function() {
    return Players.find({}, {sort: {score: -1, name: 1}});
};

Template.leaderboard.selected_name = function() {
    var player = Players.findOne(Session.get("selected_player"));
    return player && player.name;
};
```

And I would like to organize it more clearly like that:

```
Template.leaderboard = {
    players: function() {
        return Players.find({}, {sort: {score: -1, name: 1}});
    },
    selected_name: function() {
        var player = Players.findOne(Session.get("selected_player"));
        return player && player.name;
    }
};
```

The problem is (I believe from the errors in the console) that this overwrites all the existing methods of the `Template.leaderboard` object and replaces it.

Is there a possibility to add those methods to the object while keeping existing methods using the kind of notation shown above?

Comment: I think you can use prototype for that

Comment: @TomSarduy this looks like a namespace, not an "OO" object to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for [Template helpers](http://docs.meteor.com/#template_helpers)

```
Template.leaderboard.helpers({
    players: function() {
        return Players.find({}, {sort: {score: -1, name: 1}});
    },
    selected_name: function() {
        var player = Players.findOne(Session.get("selected_player"));
        return player && player.name;
    }
});
```

Comment: ah, I did wonder if Meteor had its own equivalent to ".extend" but couldn't find it.

Comment: Perfect. Good to know there is no javascript construct to do it.

Answer (score 3):

You can either add them one at a time as you've done in your first example, or you can use a method that merges an object with another, such as jQuery's `.extend`:

```
$.extend(Template.leaderboard, {
    newMethod1: function() {
        ...
    },
    newMethod2: function() {
        ...
    }
});
```

Using the latter method, you also need to be sure that `Template.leaderboard` actually exists, first!

```
var Template = Template || {};
Template.leaderboard = Template.leaderboard || {};
```

Code like the above would be typical if `Template` is actually defined across multiple JS files, and allows you to keep adding methods without regard to which order the files are actually loaded.

Answer (score 0):

There is a post here that answers this without the use of jquery or any other library.

```
function merge_options(obj1,obj2){
    var obj3 = {};
    for (var attrname in obj1) { obj3[attrname] = obj1[attrname]; }
    for (var attrname in obj2) { obj3[attrname] = obj2[attrname]; }
    return obj3;
}
```

Source:
([How can I merge properties of two JavaScript objects dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171251/how-can-i-merge-properties-of-two-javascript-objects-dynamically)).

In your case:

```
var newObject = {};

var tempObject = {
    players: function() {
        return Players.find({}, {sort: {score: -1, name: 1}});
    },
    selected_name: function() {
        var player = Players.findOne(Session.get("selected_player"));
        return player && player.name;
    }
};

for (var attrname in Template.leaderboard) {
    newObject[attrname] = Template.leaderboard[attrname];
}

for (var attrname in tempObject) {
    newObject[attrname] = tempObject[attrname];
}

Template.leaderboard = newObject;
```